# Dictionary KeyNotFoundException even though Key exists

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have a `RegistryKey` as a Key for my dictionary.

I cannot seem to set a value for that specific Key.  Whatever I do, I keep getting a `KeyNotFoundException`.  The Key does exist, I created it one line earlier

e.g:

```
public Dictionary<RegistryKey, Dictionary<string, object>> subKeyNodes = new...
subKeyNodes.Add(mainKeyNode.CreateSubKey(keyName),new Dictionary<string, object>());
subKeyNodes[mainKeyNode.CreateSubKey(keyName)].Add("ROAR", "value");
```

The Add works fine. Adding with that key value always fails and I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegistryKey` has neither a `GetHashCode` nor `Equals` override. This means instances of `RegistryKey` will use the default implementation (defined in `Object`). Because of this two instances of `RegistryKey` will not be identified as 'equal' even if their fields are the same. This means you cannot use instances of this class as a key to hashed based collections such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

As a workaround, you could define another class that wraps `RegistryKey` and defines these method overrides.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I'll try this and let you know. Btw, noway to implement GetHashCode or Equals forcefully into the class ? I was thinking something like Extensions.

Comment: wow, AND it is sealed - I hate when I'm forced to encapsulate

Answer (score 5):

A much better way is to provide something that implements `IEqualityComparer<RegistryKey>` to the constructor of the Dictionary - that way, you don't need to wrap each object.

Answer (score 2):

CreateSubKey presumably returns a new object instance each time you call it. As such, calling it twice will give you different objects (even though they may refer to the same registry key). You should store the result of the first call to CreateSubKey instead of calling it again.  Or use the key name instead of an object as your dictionary's key.

Comment: It was an example, I tried it with a variable same result. And the CreateSubKey is supposed/should return the key if its there otherwise that would of been my first issue.

Comment: Just because it's opening the same registry key doesn't mean it's the same object instance.

Comment: Have you considered using Key.Name as your key instead of the key object?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid it before so I can reference the full RegistryKey when required but since I got the problem I totally forgot about it. Though, I am going to stick with the wrapper so I can have a easy reference to the RegistryKey rather than retrieve it everytime. Thanks +1

Comment: @RezaM. Keep in mind that registry keys are disposable objects, so to be clean about your implementation, every CreateSubKey should be matched by a Close and/or Dispose. And you probably don't want to close the keys when you're putting them into the dictionary if you're going to be using those same isntances later. So you'd have to loop through every key in the dictionary and close it.